# Can a residential electrical installation require standing on a slope?

Tags: electrical

In California, an area at the back of my house has a large open north-facing wall but it's accessible via a walk-in sloped roof.

I am curious whether I can install a solar inverter on this wall?

[image: Wall]

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that they would be standing on the sloped roof to access and work on the inverter

Comment: That looks like a shingle roof to me. It will be destroyed quickly by walking on it.  As a contractor I would be reluctant to do so, as I don't want to be liable for any leaks which follow.

Comment: Are you asking about whether this would damage the roof, or are you asking about possible code restrictions on the inverter's location?

Comment: @MatthewBourque I'm asking about code restrictions on the inverter location

Answer (score 1):

You say "they would be standing on the sloped roof..." The best bet is to ask the installers, but I would also ask that they protect the roof so as not to damage the shingles, as per Harper.  (A wedge platform is pretty easy and cheep to make)
If your question is simply ..." should my roof be walked on" the answer is not without protection.

Comment: or just make a wood ladder that is purpose built to access the inverter.  if you have to work on it, put the ladder on the roof.